# Difference between pg_execute and pg_query

Tags: php, postgresql

What is difference between pg_execute and pg_query?

I have little knowledge about this.

```
pg_execute: Use to execute query with prepare statement.

pg_query: Use to execute query without prepare statement.
```

Am i right?

Can anyone explain more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first I have to explain what is prepared statement. Any query execution have to across some stages - PARSING, PLANNING + OPTIMIZATION, BINDING, EXECUTION. A result of first two stages is a execution plan. If you save it with some name, then you get a PREPARED STATEMENT. There are some reason, why you should do. One is a performance for repeated execution of SQL statements.

You can do prepared statement with statement PREPARE.

```
postgres=# PREPARE xx(text) AS SELECT * FROM pg_class WHERE relname = $1;
PREPARE
```

you can exec this prepared statement by statement EXECUTE

```
postgres=# EXECUTE xx('foo');
─[ RECORD 1 ]──┬────────────
relname        │ foo
relnamespace   │ 2200
reltype        │ 16412
reloftype      │ 0
relowner       │ 16384
```

It is similar like

```
SELECT * FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'foo'
```

but, you can use it for different parameters and you can save a some CPU time, because PARSING and PLANNING are not necessary.

so pg_execute is function for execution any prepared statement - you have to prepare prepared statement before. It is analogy to EXECUTE statement.

pg_query is used for execution query entered as string - "SELECT * FROM ...."